# Git: pre-merge hook?

Tags: git, unit-testing, selenium

I have a `pre-commit` hook that stops any commits directly to master. I want all changes to be committed to a separate branch then merged into master, only merges to master should be allowed and only if the testing suite passes.

As a separate question, would it be more appropriate to run the test suite after the merge and rollback master if the tests fail?

Comment: Usually you don’t merge directly on the server, do you? You rather push a merge from some other repository, so a `pre-merge` might not be, what you actually want. You can identify merge commits by looking at the number of parents though, so you should be able to do that with a hook that is able to look at the commit.

Comment: Im talking about people pushing to their local master branch. Since some of the tests are Selenium they must be run on a computer that has firefox. The idea is that if the tests pass and their code merges correctly with master then pushing it to the central master (staging server) should be fairly safe.

Comment: So they have to install a pre-commit in their own local repository. You can reject their push with git pre-receive hook, and put your testing suites there.